# Responsive design on desktop mode

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am having some problems with the responsive design of a landing I did. The responsive design works well on mobile and desktop, but when I activate de desktop mode on a mobile browser It just breaks. I really do not know Why this is happennig.

here is the link of the
[landing page](https://fylo-ui-landing.netlify.app/)

Comment: Make a question: Who actives the desktop browser on mobile?

Comment: Yep, probably not a lot of people, but I still would like to know why it's happening

Comment: I checked this link, seems just the footer is breaking. Try using flex-wrap property on the 4 visible block namely  Fylo description , contact mail ,about us and contact us  to adjust themselves as for the screen size. Refer this link  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap